# Date format as MM/DD/YYYY using Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime-format

I want the Date format as **MM/DD/YYYY** and I am using [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

```
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));
```

output: **"6/20/2012"**

The output I need is **"06/20/2012"**

What change should I do to get the expected result?

Answer (score 20):

Provide the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) object:

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',{month:'2-digit',day:'2-digit', year:'numeric'}).format(new Date()));
```

[Helpful Cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/wip/intl-datetime)
Available Options:

```
{
  weekday: 'narrow' | 'short' | 'long',
  era: 'narrow' | 'short' | 'long',
  year: 'numeric' | '2-digit',
  month: 'numeric' | '2-digit' | 'narrow' | 'short' | 'long',
  day: 'numeric' | '2-digit',
  hour: 'numeric' | '2-digit',
  minute: 'numeric' | '2-digit',
  second: 'numeric' | '2-digit',
  timeZoneName: 'short' | 'long',

  // Time zone to express it in
  timeZone: 'Asia/Shanghai',
  // Force 12-hour or 24-hour
  hour12: true | false,

  // Rarely-used options
  hourCycle: 'h11' | 'h12' | 'h23' | 'h24',
  formatMatcher: 'basic' | 'best fit'
}
```

Comment: Not a working solution. On my machine, it resolves to '03/17/2023'

Answer (score -3):

```
let today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Comment: This doesn't use `Intl.DateTimeFormat`? Is this on purpose?

Comment: Beware of the timezone! `toISOString` does not necessarly return the date corresponding to your timezone.